# Error during Installing WAS 6 : createprocess failed

Tags: java, websphere, failed-installation, websphere-6, ibm-was

I'm tried to install Websphere application Server Version 6 for one development project, and when I start the installation I got the error message that.

```
the JVM is not correct  and i should start the installation using -is:javahome <Java_home_DIR> Createprpocess ==> failed.
```

The problem is, at my computer I have the java sdk 1.4.2 installed and `java_home` is set correctly. The system could not find the file.

What I need to do to solve this problem, or someone knows why I'm getting this message?

Answer (score 0):

WAS Server has own java runtime environment. IBM has own version of JRE and JDK.
All installation packages are referencing to internal JRE.

Comment: hi, i try with the JRE version from IBM too but get the same error message.

Comment: How did you run your installer?

Comment: Hello @Anton, to install i start the file install.exe, file is in folder was.